# Hard to follow Taylor expansion in (Acemoglu, Autor and Patterson, 2023) - help please

Tags: taylor-expansion

I found the following analyses in the paper *Bottlenecks: sectoral imbalances and the US productivity slowdown* by Acemoglu, Autor and Patterson (2023) - working paper version [here](https://www.nber.org/system/files/working_papers/w31427/w31427.pdf). This is a paper whose core analysis is a derivation from a simple theoretical economic growth model with linkages between industries into an estimating equation that allows the authors to measure with data the importance of technological innovations to growth. More specifically, the variation of technological innovation in different sectors that creates the "bottleneck" effects alluded to in the title.

My question is about the two Taylor expansions mentioned in the figures below in section 2.1 of the paper. What I don't understand about them is how to get from (2) to (3). Below is a reproduction of the original paper, followed by my own analysis, which is hitting a brick wall. Help is very welcome, and thanks in advance!

**Figures from the original paper**

[image: Part 1 of the text]
[image: Part 2 of the text]
[image: Part 3 of the text containing the Taylor expansion]

**My own analysis**

Start with the second-order Taylor expansion at the (weighted) mean of the right-hand side of (2). By definition in the text, the weighted mean is $\bar{A}_{it}$, so the second order expansion is (please disregard the simplified notation in the summation):
$H(\bar{A}_{it}) + H'(\bar{A}_{it})(\sum_j \alpha_{ij} h(A_{jt}) - \bar{A}_{it}) + \frac{1}{2}H''(\bar{A}_{it})(\sum_j \alpha_{ij} h(A_{jt}) - \bar{A}_{it})^2$

But then some questions arise even at this stage:

- how did the weighted mean get to be *inside* $h()$ as its argument?
- where the did summation go? the intermediate result (the equation between (2) and (3), which is supposed to be the result from this second-order Taylor expansion, already dispenses with the summation.
- it was also not clear to me where the division by half normally occurring to the second-order component go as there was no factor of two that would multiply only this part

Many thanks in advance for any pointer here!